# Rewrite Url with urlManager in Yii

Tags: url, yii, url-rewriting

What must I do in order to shorten user's page url like:
http://mydomain.com/XegbmCrY

I already set a string ID for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You routes in main file should have a rule like this :-

```
'<name:[\w\_]+>' => 'user/view'
```

And your acionView in UserController should be like

```
public function actionView($name)
```

Comment: It returns error 404 when I try your suggestion. However it worked when I add the html extension. Do you have any ideas about this?